# how to create overscroll edge effect for horizontal recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I been searching web for while but unable to find right answer to create the effect when user reaches end or start of RecyclerView while scrolling.

[image]

I created Horizontal Recyclerview and i dont see overscroll edge effect. I just feel very little blue glow at the end. I would like to this kind of -

[image]

circle like effect for my Horizontal Recyclerview of my color of choice. How do i do that ?

Answer (score 4):

The overscroll color is blending too much with your listview background. That color is set by android:colorPrimary in your entire app. But If you need to specify different color use android:colorEdgeEffect.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="...">
   <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```